# Dynamically change language for datetime

Tags: babel, datetime

I am building a fairly complex letter template as `article`-extending class, which needs to be able to understand two languages (English and German). This is implemented via `babel` (with both `ngerman` and `english` as package options) and `\DeclareOption`, which uses `\selectlanguage` to determine which one.

Currently, I use `datetime` and `\today` to set the date, but that requires to load `babel` BEFORE `datetime` ([source](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/packages/datetime/datetime-manual.html#SECTION000100000000000000000)). What is the correct way to do this?

I could imagine the following, but don't know how to do any of these:

- reload `babel` so that it updates the dateformat AFTER language option has been processed
- specifiy the language for `datetime` (or use another package that supports this)
- do it manually via `ifthenelse` (I can do that, but there has to be a more elegant way?)

Thanks for your input!

Minimal Non-Working Example:

```
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}

\DeclareOption{E}{
    \selectlanguage{english}
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
% date formatting magic here please %
\today
```

Answer (score 2):

For the time being, I decided to settle with the following (this thing needs to work after all), but if somebody knows a more elegant solution, I would be happy to hear it!

```
\ifthenelse{
    \equal{\mylanguage}{german}
    }{ % german
    \renewcommand{\dateseparator}{.}
    }{ % english
    \renewcommand{\dateseparator}{/}
    }
    \ddmmyyyydate
    \today
```